# Significato di "gesto" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Ormai erano arrivati tutti, ci avevano baciati sulle guance, dicevano: – Noi ci vediamo sempre solo in queste occasioni, – si sedevano e aspettavano il caffè. Nostra madre glielo passò, dicendo a tutti la stessa cosa: – Eh, che **gesto** mi son vista, – e poi dovette mandarmi a comperarne per altre due once.

La scena accade durante il funerale del padre dell'io narrante, che era morto perché era caduto nel pozzo quando era andato a cercare l'acqua.

Ho cercato il termine "gesto" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il significato nel contesto di questo testo. Me lo sapreste spiegare?